# Binding a irregular URL encoded POST request with Nancy

Tags: post, nancy, dhtmlx

I'm supposed to make an old sqlite database editable trough a Sketchup Plugin in its WebDialog. Sketchups Ruby is not able to install the sqlite3 gem and since I already need to display the table in a WebDialog, I opted for a micro service with the help of Nancy. The existing Plugin already uses the [dhtmlxSuite](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxSuite/) and its Grid Component is exactly what I need. They even offer a `Connector` that can send requests based on the actions of the user in the grid.

They also offer a connector for the server side, but that *too* does not work with sqlite. I already managed to connect to my database, used `Dapper` to bin the result of an SQL query to an object and return that data with a manually crafted JSON object. Very hacky, but it populates the data successful.

Now the client-`Connector` sends data manipulated by the user (delete and insert is forbidden) back with an url encoded POST request that looks quite weird:

```
4_gr_id=4&4_c0=0701.041&4_c1=Diagonale%20f%3Fr%202.07%20X%201.50%20m&4_c2=AR&4_c3=8.3&4_c4=380&4_c5=38.53&4_c6=0&4_c7=0&4_!nativeeditor_status=updated&ids=4
```

I'm not sure exactly why the hell they would use the row index inside the key for the key-value pairs, but this just makes my life that much harder. The only thing that comes to my mind is extracting the data I'm interested in with a regex, but that sounds even worse than what I did before.

Any suggestions for me how I could map that POST request to something usable?

Comment: Not sure where the Nancy bit is here, Nancy doesn't route bind on the query string.  You can easily convert the query string into a list of key-value pais (kvps), but then you're on your own, won't you need to reverse-engineer their POST data format?

Comment: I just didn't know what Nancy can offer me. In the end, I settled of using a regex to get around their data format, extracting the relevant columns and storing it back in the database. It actually works, but isn't as elegant as I'd like it.

Comment: Is the regex more useful than matching the route (i.e. the left-hand part before the querystring) and then extracting the keys and values from the querystring (the url decoding should be done automatically)?  That would be simple to test out and see what you get.  In the Get[], see what you have in this.Request.Query